# Angular keep on the same page unless form is filled

Tags: angular

After User is logged In, They go to form. which has name and username.

```
http://localhost:4200/form
```

I want user to fill the form and then redirect to any other page. How do I make sure that even if user change the url they won't go anywhere unless they fill the form.

app-routing.module.ts

```
  {
    path: "create-profile/:username",
    component: profileComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
```

now when user login it goes to this component.

```
submit(form: any) {
    this.username = form.username;
    this.name= form.name;
    this.auth.changePassword(form).subscribe(data => {
      this.snackBar.open("profile created", "close", {
        duration: 3000
      });
    });
  }
```

now after this I am not sure what should I do? I am still new to angular

Answer (score 1):

Your solution would be a two step process:

1. Create a service to store the status of the form. Eg: valid/invalid. A common scenario is maintaining if a user is logged-in, has access, etc.
2. Create a **route guard** for other routes and check the status of the form using the service from #1 to allow/disallow navigation.

Please have a look at https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

Comment: I will need some coding example to clear the concept. I know both of them, but I am not sure how do I implement them

Comment: Can you share some code of what you have tried till now ?

Comment: I have updated my question. please check. also I have Auth guards but that checks if user is logged In or not!

Comment: Here is a working stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqc2xv. I have not actually created a form, but mimicked the form fill state using a simple button in the `formComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

in submit you can check:-

```
submit(form: any){
  if (form.valid) {
    //write your auth gurd service code here to check 
}
}
```

in your route file:-
you can write like this

```
{ path: '', redirectTo:'login', pathMatch="full" canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
```

AuthGuard is service that you can write